# Get characters after a word in Python

Tags: python, regex

I've been trying for hours to do this in Python and I don't know what else to do.
I have a string similar to this:

```
title = "Marielizabeth's Diary Chapter 9"
```

I want to get the number after the word "chapter" and then put a 0 in front of it: "Marielizabeth's Diary Chapter 09". I can't use title.replace because I don't know what I'll get. I only know that the number is after the word "chapter".

```
chapter = title.split('Chapter ', 1)
for char in chapter:
 print char
```

But it doesn't work. How can I do this?

Final solution:

```
title = "Marielizabeth's Diary Chapter 9"
re.sub('Chapter (\d$)', lambda m: "0" + m.group(1), title)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a function inside the `repl` argument of [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
>>> import re
>>> title = "Marielizabeth's Diary Chapter 9"
>>> re.sub('Chapter (\d)', lambda m: "0" + m.group(1), title)
"Marielizabeth's Diary 09"
```

Here `(\d)` is a capturing group that matches a single digit.

Comment: You don't necessarily need the (\d+) instead of (\d). Both will match "Chapter 9"

Comment: @MartinKonecny yup, wasn't sure about whether match one or multiple digits, let's see what the OP would say. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If your problem statement is 100% accurate, there is a very simple way, use the replace method and replace "Chapter " with "Chapter 0"

e.g.

```
title = "Marielizabeth's Diary Chapter 9"
title = title.replace("Chapter ", "Chapter 0")
```

This depends upon a single space between chapter and the following number, i.e., an exact match to your problem statement.

Comment: "I can't use title.replace because I don't know what I'll get." -OP

Comment: This is a nice answer, though still not sure if `Chapter 10` should be replaced with `Chapter 010`. Probably the OP wants to "catch" a single digit only.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their answers! Yes, I need to replace it only if it's single digit.

Comment: Yes, I answered this after the regex based answer by you (alecxa) was already posted -- a certainly more general approach. It is just that clever use of replace can be an incredibly simple and fast solution sometimes that people overlook because regex is potent. Problem definition is definitely the key to writing the correct solution.

Comment: @GaryWalker yeah, seeing a bigger picture :)

Comment: Both of your answers work, but they put a 0 even if the number is greater than 10. Any ideas? :)

Comment: I only had one answer. Did you mean both mine and alecxe? Use the re based solution and add the $ (end of line) after \d to force it to match only a single digit.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm is a succinct python re summary -- worth a gander.

Comment: Yes, alecxe's answer and yours solved my problem. Now it works perfectly!

Comment: Why not add your "final solution" to your original question -- easier for someone else to figure since it may be a bit hard to follow.